# No Thumbnails Generated

Tags: uploads, post-thumbnails, server, images

I setup WordPress on my own server and it's up and running...one thing that I have noticed is that WordPress doesn't generate any images I upload. Usually when I upload an image through WordPress it will generate a thumbnail, medium, and large sized image. WordPress installed without error and everything else is working fine. I have tried to rebuild the thumbnails, but that doesn't work :-(

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I figured it out!

In my php.ini file I had to uncomment `extension=php_gd2.dll`, then it started working after I rebuilt the images I uploaded :)

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: The need of the gd extension was indeed the problem for me. On my CentOS server I just had to `yum install php-gd` and `service httpd restart` though. Thanks for pointing me in the direction!

Comment: Same issue here... Installing and enabling the php-gd extension did the trick. Of course, WordPress did not produce any warning  In passing, this also restores the "Edit Image" button.

Answer (score 3):

I solved the issue as well.

With reference to Josh Rodgers' answer, I had to log into my server's CPANEL, under "Software and Services", depending on how your server is set up, there is "Select PHP Version", then tick the "gd" box, save, and refresh your wordpress post or media page, then retry the upload.

If you are looking at your wordpress via FTP, you can refresh your uploads folder and see that the various sizes have appeared, i.e. imagename100x100.jpg, etc, etc.

I hope this helps someone.

Bernard

Comment: For WHM users, go to EasyApache > Exhaustive Options > PHP, check GD and rebuild Apache. Source: https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/how-to-install-php-gd-library.127773/

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem on my new server install with Ubuntu 16.04 and PHP 5.6. The problem is that Wordpress relies on the PHP GD module in order to generate the thumbnails. The insight from Josh led me to install the GD module using this command via SSH:

`sudo apt install php5.6-gd`

And then restarting apache:

`sudo service apache2 restart`

Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough reputation to comment @guilherme-vaz answer. His solution worked but I had to check which version I am using.

Use `php -v` cmd to find php version you are using, and then install gd. In my case it was 7.1. So I did `sudo apt install php7.1-gd` and restart apache `sudo service apache2 restart`

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the most useful answer, but it is another variation - which I just spent a couple hours on.

I did just go through this......   **and it was actually the file**.

My site was throwing a hard 500 error after the initial upload of a few files - so apparently the thumbnail process.
I got a couple files to fully upload individually, but not this one.
As with other people, I could see the file in the library, but without a preview image, and it did not have any usable images for the file if I tried to insert it.

I don't know how I have this magic file that breaks WP.
It opens fine on my laptop.

But with trying additional, individual files at the request of my hosting company, it became clear it was actually the specific file --  more than a little unexpected.

**I re-created the file in a different format and that was the end of it.**

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 16.04 PHP 7.0 here.

Was missing GD extension on my PHP install.

Had to do

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-gd
sudo service apache2 restart
```

And that fixed it.

Note that before searching for "gd" in my PHP info gave just 1 result, after there was not a whole section about GD.

source: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/is-there-a-php-gd-command-for-php7