# Edit Image/Image Details - Replace button missing

Tags: php, jquery, uploads, media, media-library

I have a strange problem. I am dynamically populating content into Wordpress' tinyMCE editor. Part of this content is a placeholder image, that the user can then replace. The issue is when I click the 'pencil' icon to edit, I am not given the "Replace" button like I would any other images.

This is what I see: [image]

This is what I expect, and works on images imported from the media library: [image]

**Notice, the replace button is present in the second example. I guess because the image is hard-linked and wordpress has no way of knowing if the image exists in the media library. How can I dynamically import an image so this functionality is present?**

Comment: In my case, [installing and enabling the PHP GD extension](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/85813/68251) restored the missing "Edit Image" button.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This has something to do with the HTML of a media object. I copy/pasted code from another image imported from the media gallery and it worked. Use this function to insert the content:

http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:method.tinymce.Editor.setContent

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent('<span>some</span> html');
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you `dynamically populate content into Wordpress`.

To get the Edit Image Button the image must be in the `Media`. Make sure the image has a `class="wp-image-{ID}"` where `{ID}` has to be the right maching id of the image you can find via media content. Or while inserting the image and have a look at the source code then you will find that class with the right `{ID}`