# WordPress stopped generating image thumbnails after changing hosting environment

Tags: post-thumbnails

I moved my WP website from shared hosting, to Digital Ocean LEMP stack droplet. I noticed that thumbnails aren't generated any more for new post featured images, I also tried manually  regenarating thumbnails for specific images, it succeeds but nothing generated.

I tried deactivation of the **Force Regenerate Thumbnails** plugin and activating it again, but still no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: Related? https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/85803/no-thumbnails-generated

Comment: Wordpress needs certain libraries installed on your hosts server to do that. You can add a new php file with the `phpinfo()` function in it, and when you load that file in your browser search for Imagick, and GD. If they aren’t installed or activated then install Imagick. 

This post describes the libraries, and what versions are needed for webp support if you want that. 

https://make.wordpress.org/core/2021/06/07/wordpress-5-8-adds-webp-support/

Comment: @BenHartLenn Thanks, your answer was really helpful!